# UIView created in IB has no frame in viewDidLoad and awakeFromNib

Tags: ios, uiview

I'm sorry if I missed something here, but I thought UIView objects that were created in IB should have their frames created in viewDidLoad so you can do initial setup based off of this view in viewDidLoad or awakeFromNib or viewWillAppear.  I logged the output in each method:

```
NSLog(@"%@ %s", NSStringFromCGRect(self.zoomView.frame), __FUNCTION__);
```

And in all I get {0, 0, 0, 0}.

This is the first nib in my UIStoryboard, and I'm using Autolayout and iOS 6.  I could have sworn on previous apps I have used the frame of other UIView objects created in IB to set things up.  Is there something that has changed?  Or do I just remember it incorrectly?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you 1000% sure that the IBOutlet is linked to the view?

Comment: @0x7fffffff Yes I am 100% positive the IBOutlet is connected.  I disconnected it and reconnected it to make sure that was not the issue.

Comment: If it is definitely linked, are you calling alloc/init on this view at any point?

Comment: I am having this problem too. And I noticed that in viewDidAppear it's not  {0, 0, 0, 0} anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. Yes, you remember correctly - it used to be different in iOS 5. I always set up my views in `viewDidLoad:` and the frame was already the way it was going to be when the view was actually on screen.

Now in iOS 6, you'll need to put your code into `viewDidAppear:` to have a valid frame to work with, if [auto layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/) is enabled. Apparently the laying-out is done in between those two calls.

Comment: If you want to enable in both simple disable Autolayout option.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the device you are using and possibly other things but the frames and bounds "could" sometimes be set by the time viewDidLoad is invoked and sometimes not (depends on ....) On the other hand, frames and bounds are guaranteed to have been set by the time "ViewDidAppear" has been called. And you want to put your code related to frames and bounds where it is guaranteed!